# Why are there two definite articles in "el primero al que..."?

Tags: gramática

I am struggling to understand the grammar behind the sentence "Sé el primero al que le gusta esto", and in particular that construction "el primero al que". I understand "que" to here mean "that" or "who", and the "a" is simply the personal "a", but I cannot see past a literal translation of "the first the who". Why is it not simply "Sé el primero **a** que le gusta esto"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [definite article - and the use of "al"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/definite-article-and-the-use-of-al)

Comment: _al_ is the [contracted article](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/definite-article-and-the-use-of-al?rq=1) for _a el_ and, in this case, means: _to whom_ **it** likes.

Answer (score 2):

The most usual relative pronoun for people is "que".
*Sé el primero que hace clic.*

But, as we are using the pronoun in the I.O. (because "gustar" asks for it), we find ourselves with a preposition.

After a preposition, the presence (as opposed to the absence) of an article depends on several things:

- Explanatory clause, mandatory: *Mi marido, al que le gusta eso, dice...*
- Restrictive clause, depends:

  - Non person: different rules, depending on whether it's a, de, con, en , por; whether it's affirmative or emphatic... Not our case here.
  - Person, mandatory. **<- Our case.**

Source: [DPD, "que", 1.2.2](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW)

Comment: The OP does not indicate a person. Also "una persona en que confío" is a clear example of a person (literally) that does not require the article between the preposition and *que*

Comment: @guifa I'd say (point me to a reliable source if I'm wrong, please) that, although it sounds "well", it's as incorrect as "una persona con que fui". Also, we are addressing a second person singular, we can assume the personhood of the subject ("you who have the ability to like").

Comment: I don't agree with _sé el primero que hace clic_, this is not what the link suggest, unless you just like to do click wherever you can. Neither with the affirmation of _que_ as the most usual relative pronoun, you need to attach statistics if you are going to say that.

Comment: That was just an example of usage of what OP seemed to find intuitive, in no way I'm suggesting that the meaning of the original sentence is that one, I'm just trying to illustrate a correct instance of "que" without the article. The answer to OPs question is not that, it's below that. Edit: as for frequencies, this might hint in that direction http://www.uwosh.edu/faculty_staff/cortes/classes/Fall%202010/301/pronombresrelativos.html Double-edit: this one has no comic sans: http://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/12/12_0169.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The word **que** is a *relative pronoun* (equivalent to the English word **that**).

In normal use you must put it together after the other word which makes the syntactic relation. (This is not entirely true, but it avoids complicating the explanation). For example:

> El **televisor que** compramos está defectuoso.

The grammatical analysis is as follows:

1. Main clause: *El televisor está defectuoso*
2. Subordinate clause: *que compramos*

The subordinate clause can be expanded to *el televisor compramos* ("we buy a TV"), where the pronoun "que" replaces "televisor". That is the function of relative pronouns.

You cannot separate *televisor* from *que*.

Now consider your hypothetical sentence:

> Sé el **primero** a **que** le gusta esto

In this case the preposition **a** is "sandwiched" between *primero* and *que*.

The solution is to use a slightly more complex pronoun. It seems as if we only add an article, but it is actually considered *another type* of relative pronoun, that agrees in gender and number with what it's related to:

> el que, la que, los que, las que.

With this pronoun we can do more complicated things:

> **El que** llegue primero ganará. [At the beginning of sentence]
>
> Sé la primera a **la que** le gusta esto. [Preceded by a preposition]
>
> Sé el primero a **el que** le gusta esto.

...but in this last case we merge **a + el** into one word **al**:

> Sé el primero **al que** le gusta esto.

When referring to humans you can also use the pronoun **quien**, which works identically, but only agrees in number (not gender):

> Sé el primero a **quien** le gusta esto.
>
> Sean los primeros a **quienes** les gusta esto.

Answer (score 1):

It can be just *que*. The "short" prepositions — a, de, con — allow for the omission (or perhaps better said, elision) of the article.

The reason the article is needed is because all prepositions in Spanish must have a noun or something acting as a noun following them. Proposition standing, common in English, is verboten.

A *que* clause you see is actually an adjective clause, though. To nounify adjectives, in other words, to say a thing that is that adjective, we place an article in front.

Comment: If you use just _que_ then the sentence will be: _Sé el primero que gusta de esto_, which is not too natural for me but it's common in Spain.

Comment: @SergioVelásquez That is a different structure.  Per DPD ***que** 1.2.2.2.*, "Si el antecedente no es de persona, el relativo con preposición puede construirse opcionalmente sin artículo en los siguientes casos: a) Con las preposiciones a, con, de, en y por […] En todos estos casos es igualmente posible el uso del relativo con artículo e, incluso, suele ser lo más habitual, especialmente en el caso de *por*, ya que la secuencia *por que* puede tener también otro valor […] b) Cuando la oración de relativo es afirmativa […] ".

Comment: Based on that, "Sé el primero al que le gusta esto" and "Sé el primero a que le gusta esto" are both valid unless (per DPD ***que** 1.2.2.2.*, if the modified noun is a person, the article is obligatory, but in the OP's question, it is not specified whether it is a person, thus making the article optional)

Comment: You missunderstood the explanation _Sé el primero a que le gusta esto_ will not be accepted by a native. "...ha de llevarlo necesariamente cuando el antecedente es de persona". in the sentence _al_, the article _el_ is referring to the person (the one who likes it (it is: me, clicking the like button)), so, in this case, the use of _al_ is mandatory.

Comment: There is nothing in the sentence to indicate that this is a person and not *toros* or figuratively about something completely different (and, in any case, that rule is clearly not absolute: *la persona **en que** confío*). No native that I've ever met would say *las razones por que se hace* (they'd all use *por **las** que*), but it's perfectly valid. Just because someone might not use a structure doesn't negate its technical correctness (e.g. "The rat the cat the man adopted caught was eaten").

Comment: you are mixing things. The context is one person on its computer, mobile, or whatever dispositive viewing something in an application and there is a link that suggest `Sé el primero al que le gusta esto`. That's why **al** (a el) makes reference to a person, who is going, or not, to click the link. About the use of _en que_, you're right with the example sentence and then you can say _Sé el primero en gustar de esto_ (but it's different to the use of **al**.

Comment: Where did you get this context? I don't see that in the post

Comment: It's just the clearest example I can find based on the web applications I know, where the link is present, for me is very clear from the original post. Also can be used when someone cooks something and has confidence and, in a friendly form, suggest you that.